# How to use subqueries in ServiceStack ORMLite

Tags: linq-to-sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack ORMLite and need to perform a query such below:

```
SqlServerExpressionVisitor<Contact> sql = new SqlServerExpressionVisitor<Contact>();
SqlServerExpressionVisitor<Account> accSql = new SqlServerExpressionVisitor<Account>();

var finalSql = sql.Where(a=> 
   (from a1 in accSql where a1.Type == "Client" 
   && a1.Id==a.AccountId select a1).Any());
```

When perform this query, i get a lambda error "a" is not defined in the scope. "a" here is the reference to the variable defined for the parent Where method call.

How can I use the ExpressionVisitor to perform subqueries in the WHERE clause?

UPDATE:
I created my own SqlServiceExpressionVisitor which allows me to customize how ORM generates the SQL statements. I also added class such as below:

```
public static class SQL
{
    public static bool ExistsIn<T>(T Value, string subquery, params T[] parameters)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ExistsIn<T, TItem>(T Value, SqlExpressionVisitor<TItem> innerSql)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static SqlExpressionVisitor<T> Linq<T>() 
    {
        return OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<T>();
    }
}
```

Then extended the VisitMethodCall to take my new class into account and call my custom method accordingly:

```
internal object VisitSQLMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
{
    string methodName = m.Method.Name;
    if (methodName == "ExistsIn")
    {
        string quotedColName = Visit(m.Arguments[0] as Expression).ToString();
        dynamic visit = Visit(m.Arguments[1]);

        string innerQuery = (visit is string) ? visit.ToString().Trim('"') : visit.ToSelectStatement();
        if (m.Arguments[2] != null)
        {
            List<object> fields = VisitExpressionList((m.Arguments[2] as NewArrayExpression).Expressions);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
               innerQuery = innerQuery.Replace("@" + count.ToString(), field.ToString());
               count++;
            }
        }

        return new PartialSqlString(string.Format("{0} IN ({1})", quotedColName, innerQuery));
    }
}
```

**The results are very promising, here is how it can be used:**

```
.Where(a => SQL.ExistsIn(a.AccountId, SQL.Linq<Account>()
    .Where(acc => acc.Name.Contains("a")).Select(acc => acc.Id)))
```

Above generates the proper inner SQL, however if I include a reference from the parent Query, again the system calls the return Expression.Lambda(m).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); which produce the same error!

```
SQL.Linq<Contact>().Where(a => SQL.ExistsIn(a.AccountId, SQL.Linq<Account>()
  .Where(acc => acc.Id == a.AccountId).Select(acc => acc.Id)))
```

The above generates the error: parameter "a" is not defined in the scope.
I guess i only need to somehow add a parameter definition to the second Visit call in my custom method but I have not figured out how yet!
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Although I know ORMLite new version can handle joins, I'd rather use another ORM such as Dapper to solve the joins between two or more tables. I find Dapper more powerful on this part.

Comment: I have not seen any documentation on Dapper that would support Linq to SQL. Also I feel like I understand the ORMLite code better and it is written very nicely.

Answer (score 4):

There is no documentation in the Wiki; you need to look at the code to see how to use the join feature. For your problem the code should look something like this :

```
        var jb = new JoinSqlBuilder<Contact, Account>()
            .Join<Contact, Account>(x => x.AccountId, x => x.Id)
            .Where<Account>(x => x.Type == "Client")
            .SelectCount<Contact>(x => x.Id);
        var sqlStr = jb.ToSql();
        bool isAvailable = dbManager.Connection.SqlScalar<int>(sqlStr) > 0;
```

For complex subqueries, the current version of JoinBuilder is not useful. I personally use DbExtensions from http://www.nuget.org/packages/DbExtensions/ along with Ormlite. Since I have extended Ormlite's T4 to automatically generate the Column name, Table, I use the DbExtension like this :

```
        SqlBuilder builder = new SqlBuilder();
        builder = builder.SELECT("*").
                FROM(Contact.TABLE_NAME).WHERE(Contact.COLUMN_AccountId +" = " + id.ToString());
        var sql = builder.ToString();
        return dbConnection.FirstOrDefault<Contact>(sql, builder.ParameterValues.ToArrayEx());
```

Comment: I was more looking for a solution that ties everything back to the SqlServerExpressionVisitor. In terms of API, if I want to let other developers use it, I'd rather stick to one stream of API. In case the developer needs go to two separate path one using the SqlServerExpressionVisitor and the other JoinSqlBuilder. Plus for what I need to do, no join is required. I only need the subquery.

I am not sure how EF does this, but thorough IQueryable interface they have made all of this possible.

Comment: If you are just looking to use a ExpressionVisitor, unfortunately you cannot use subqueries with it. The way EF works is that it parses the child expressions generate Sqls. If you just want to use a Linq based solution, I would suggest you to look at linq2db - http://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db/ && https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db